# Shrinking text to fit inside parentheses

Tags: math-mode

I have a fraction written inside parentheses.  Instead of increasing the size of the parentheses using `\left(` or `\big(`, I actually want the fraction to automatically shrink.  (Specifically, I want it to resize so that it does not extend beyond the vertical bounds of the size of a default `(`.)

What is the simplest way to do this manually?  And is there a rule I can implement at the top of my document so that this always happens automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The symbol $(\frac{n^\alpha}{(1 + p)^n})$ is taller than the parentheses,
so it extends below and above them, which I don't want.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\scalebox` from the `\graphicx` package, or perhaps the `relsize` package.

Comment: Scaling down the box is really bad style and the text will be hardly readible, instead you should flatten your fraction `$((n^\alpha)/(1 + p)^n)$` or use display equation, whatever fits better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't recommend it because it is really bad style, you could scale the content using `\resizebox{!}{<height>}{..}` or `\scalebox{<factor>}{..}` from the `graphicx` package. You might want to raise the baseline using `\raisebox{<amount>}{..}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
The symbol $($\resizebox{!}{\heightof{$()$}}{$\frac{n^\alpha}{(1 + p)^n}$}$)$ is taller than the parentheses,
so it extends below and above them, which I don't want.

The symbol $($\raisebox{.1ex}{\resizebox{!}{1.4ex}{$\frac{n^\alpha}{(1 + p)^n}$}}$)$ is taller than the parentheses,
so it extends below and above them, which I don't want.

\end{document}
```

The `adjustbox` package can also be used to simplify the command, e.g. `\adjustbox{height=<height>,raise=<amount>}{..}`. Also try `totalheight` instead of `height` and see if the results fit better.

Comment: neat! hadn't thought of it as "graphic" material!

Comment: @Koji: Usually you shouldn't ;-)

Comment: @Koji: Note that the scaling and resizing commands are needed to include images in a given size, so they are added to `graphicx`. They also work on other things like text or math.

Answer (score 2):

My best shot would be `$(\frac{\scriptscriptstyle n^\alpha}{\scriptscriptstyle(1 + p)^n})$`, but that is also bigger that the regular parenthesis (besides looking horrible).

Would you consider `$n^\alpha/(1+p)^n$`?

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that your question is raised in the hopes of not needing to remember to use `\left/\right/\bigs` (or something), how about `\def\pfrac#1#2{ {#1 \overwithdelims() #2} }`? `amsmath` will nag though, but not error.